# NSTimer responding to a uibutton

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nstimer

So, Here is the problem.  I am trying to make a timer for my game however it doesnt seem to run.

I started by making a property for nstimer:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSTimer gameTimer;
```

and synthesizing it:

```
@synthesize gameTimer = _gameTimer;
```

then I use this method to set it:

```
-(NSTimer *) gameTimer{
    if (_gameTimer == nil) _gameTimer = [[NSTimer alloc]init];
    return _gameTimer;
}
```

however when i try to start the timer through a uibutton:

```
- (IBAction)play:(UIButton *)sender {

    _levelNumber = 1;
    _en1v = -1;
    _en2v = 1;
    _en3v = -1;
    [self setPath];
    _gameTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self     selector:@selector(onTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    self.play.hidden = TRUE;
}
```

it doesn't work.

I put an nslog into the onTimer: method and found out that the timer just isn't firing some how?

Am I making an obvious mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not started the timer at all.

Use:

```
_gameTimer =  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(onTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

And while stopping, (may be in `stop:` method)

```
[_gameTimer invalidate];
_gameTimer = nil;
```

Comment: ahhh, thanks.  I wasn't using scheduled timer, now its working.

Comment: You can also just do `[_gameTimer fire];` to maintain `timerWithTimeInterval...`